# c++ passing a char to glShaderSource

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader

So I keep getting the error "invalid conversion from  char** to const GLchar** ". I've read similar posts on here about this error but i still cant seem to fix it so any help would be much appreciated. Below are snippets from my opengl c++ program.
I have a char function that is declared as follows:

```
char *loadShaderFile(char *fileName)
```

In a different function i do the following:

```
    char *vertexShaderSource = loadShaderFile((char *)"vshader.glsl");
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    free(vertexShaderSource);
```

Comment: Did you try using the keyword `const` ?´

Comment: FYI that typecast: ``char *`` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `const` qualifier before `char *` pointer declaration like below:

```
const char *vertexShaderSource = loadShaderFile((char *)"vshader.glsl");
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
free(vertexShaderSource);
```

Comment: Adding const qualifier gave me a different error but i ended up temporarily fixing it by removing the line that deallocated the memory. Thanks